# Formula to figure 5% difference between two columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Hello I have two columns in excel, both with different percentage numbers (100%, 75%) what formula could I use to highlight a column in which column A is a 5% difference or more than column B?

Comment: `5% difference` – Percent or [percentage point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage_point)?

Answer (score 1):

use absolute:

```
=ABS(A1-B1)>=.05
```

Comment: Scott Craner's answer gets you the formula, use it in conditional formatting to get the row highlighted